# SQL SUM JOIN Issue

Tags: sql, join, sum

I come to you again seeking further help :)  I have gotten to the point where I am able to JOIN the two queries producing the duplicate columns with different values as I would like, but I am still facing the overall query producing many results for each size (literal and technical are 1:1) How could I go about producing a query that only shows each material once for each size?  Thanks in advance and thanks for all of your help:

```
SELECT * 
FROM


(SELECT         P.PLANT_CODE,
                P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P.PERIOD_CODE,
                P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P.PLANNED_QTY AS 'REM PLAN QTY',
                P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.PLANNED_QTY + P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'ORIGINAL FCST QTY'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.PLANT_CODE IN ('6040','6041')
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 AND            P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00','01','ZU','Z2')
 AND            P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - 59
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY > 0) AS P1

 JOIN      

 (SELECT
                SUM(P.PLANNED_QTY) AS 'FUTURE_FCST',
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE > GETDATE()
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY > 0
 GROUP BY       P.PLANNED_QTY,
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL) AS P2

 ON             P1.MATERIAL = P2.MATERIAL
 AND            P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = P2.TECHNICAL_INDEX`

 ORDER BY       P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX;
```

Comment: I think I may  have solved this - it appears I DO NOT need to include P.PLANNED_QTY in the GROUP BY clause as it is an aggregate function.  It is looking good so far but let me know if you guys see anything else fishy.

Comment: Oops one more question - I have GETDATE() -59 up there but the Access query I am rebuilding from has a weird function I have never seen where you enter a number for the day of the week you are running the report...is there anything like this in SQL Server?

Comment: No, you don't need `PLANNED_QTY` in the `GROUP BY` (it's almost certainly making the results incorrect); you probably don't need to reference it in the `WHERE` clause either (given it won't effect the sum...).  I'd also pull the non-aggregate query up a level, you don't need to do a subquery here.  What's your RDBMS vendor/version?  And could we get sample source data and desired results?  Something better may be available (like the use of an `OVER` clause...)

Comment: Using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.  You will have to forgive me I am not sure what the best way to upload data would be?

Comment: Desired results are essentially to show a past (60 days) demand for a material, how much of that demand has been withdrawn (WITHRDAWN_QUANTITY) as a sum and future demand (no WITHDRAWN needed) by size (technical is another term for literal, just two different systems)

Comment: Technically SQL Server Management Studio 2012 is _not_ your db, but a tool that interfaces with it (although the implication is that your db is SQL Server 2012).  Sample data is usually just posted as a formatted table (look at other questions for some examples), usually with only 'required' columns (ie, eliminate most columns referenced only in the `SELECT` clause).  You're summing the _total_ future forecast, but only comparing against a restricted historical set, why?  This seems slightly strange...

Comment: I see.  I do believe the company uses Oracle - I use SQL Server because I am more comfortable with it.  I see what you are saying and I guess the best way for me to explain it is everything hinges on P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE.  I need to consolidate the first query with the second query.  The first query is dynamic, in that stock is being moved out and is reflected in the 'WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY" column.  The future does not matter for that - just need to know the sum of future demand.